# select TOP (1) -> does seek -> but still high logical read count

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns 1 row - it has a covering index - but logical reads can still get into the hundreds.

When I rebuild index - the logical reads will go to 4.

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
SELECT TOP (1) Id, WayId, CmpId, Ack, DateAck, AckBy 
FROM csn_comppricing.dbo.XQueue
WHERE Id = 1 AND Ack = 0 
ORDER BY BucketScore DESC, Score DESC, DateAck ASC;
```

--Here is index that covers the query

```
create index IX_X on dbo.X (ID, BucketScore desc, Score desc, DateAck) 
include(Ack, WayId, CmpId, AckBy) where Ack = 0 with (pad_index=on, fillfactor=50, online=on);
```

Here is last IO stats:
Table 'X'. Scan count 1, logical reads 65, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

I have seen up to 800 logical reads for this query.

After a rebuild the logical reads will go to 4.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY70s.png)

Comment: what does the execution plan show, before and after rebuild?

Comment: If a rebuild "fixes" things, is strongly suggests your index is suffering from high degrees of fragmentation, or lagging statistics. Schedule periodic reorganization/rebuilding, or use some of the more popular pre-made scripts for this (like Ola Hallengren's). `PAD_INDEX` and `FILLLFACTOR` will do little on their own as they only have an effect when the index is created, not as it subsequently fills up and pages need to be reordered. Setting the fill factor as high as 50 (leaving pages half empty) is rather extreme, but still no help if you don't maintain the index.

Comment: Move Ack to the first position in the Key columns... I've never found any clear documentation to corroborate this, but it's been my experience that SQL Server makes better use of filtered indexes when the filter predicate columns are in the first key positions.

Comment: The execution plan is the same before and after rebuild.

Comment: How does fragmentation cause 10X reads (15 in this case)? Even if an index is highly fragmented - it would still seek using just a few pages.

Comment: The filtered index was just a try, with or without the filtered index indexes get high logical read counts.